# Collapsed keyboard, toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, keyboard

[image: collapsed keyboard]

How can I check when keyboard is shown fully and when collapsed like this? Maybe can I check it height?

I checked `userInfo` from `notification` for now and I found nothing useful for resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just subscribe to notifications:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(self.adjustForKeyboard), name: 
NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(self.adjustForKeyboard), name: 
NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
```

and paste next method nearly

```
func adjustForKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    if  let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let keyboardViewEndFrame = delegate.getView().convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: delegate.getView().window)

        var customInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero            
        if notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide {
            customInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        } else {
            customInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
        }

        scrollView.contentInset = customInset
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = customInset
    }
}
```

don't forget to remove observer when you left this VC

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```